# How should a UTF-8 decoder handle invalid codepoints (surrogates, larger than 0x10ffff) correctly?

Tags: utf-8

I'm writing a UTF-8 decoder, and I don't know how to handle invalid codepoints correctly:

- surrogates
- codepoints larger than 0x10ffff

Suppose, that I'd like to replace invalid codepoints with 0xfffd. Now, how should I replace them? Immediately after I know that the codepoint cannot be valid, or should I decode/consume all bytes that the first byte mandates?

For example, suppose, that the UTF-8 stream contains: `0xf4 0x90 0x80 0x80`

These bytes decode to `0x110000`, an invalid codepoint.

But, at the second byte, when `0xf4 0x90` is processed, I know, that it cannot be a valid codepoint, no matter what the last two bytes are.

So, should this stream generate one error (and one replacement), or should it generate 3 errors (because `0xf4 0x90` is invalid, and then `0x80` and the other `0x80` is invalid as well)?

Is there a standard which mandates this? If not, what could be the best practice?

Comment: You forgot over-long Encodings.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer in the unicode standard, [chapter 03](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode11.0.0/ch03.pdf), pages 126-129:

- unicode standard mandates that a well-formed subsequence must not be consumed as a part of ill-formed sequence (my example doesn't contain such a case, though)
- there is a recommendation to follow W3C: one error should be generated for a *maximal subpart* of an ill-formed subsequence (see the definition in the linked document)
- the second byte of `0xf4 0x90 0x80 0x80` is invalid, so I should generate **4** errors if the recommendation is followed (because the 2nd byte is invalid, the maximal subpart at the beginning is just `0xf4`)

If my example have been `0xf4 0x8f 0x41`, then I should generate **1** error only, as `0xf4 0x8f` is a maximal subpart, and `0x41` is a well-formed subsequence.

Answer (score 1):

The Unicode Consortium seems to be concerned only with accuracy (not dropping good bytes) and security (not putting two pieces of good text together because a security scanner might have given the text a pass when considering the bad bytes but perhaps would have blocked the cleaned up text). It allows others to define any specific practices. (It seems that had proposed best practices but will [back away](http://www.unicode.org/L2/L2017/17344r2-clarify-utf8.pdf) since W3C has formalized them.)

W3C is concerned with security, of course, but also with the consistency you ask for. It says to error (e.g. insert the replacement character) for every ill-formed subsequence, per its very detailed [reference UTF-8 Decoder algorithm](https://www.w3.org/TR/encoding/#utf-8-decoder).